# Php ICal updating the meeting request

Tags: php

I am able to send the `Ical` request to outlook through my application, but I can't understand how to update the request. i.e if user has already raised the meeting request for 10.00 am and now wants to change the meeting time to 11.00 am.

How to update previously sent request without sending the new one